# Installing Java API for GPIB devices in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, api, jar, gpib

This is probably a trivial question, but I am having trouble installing a Java API called JPIB_Windows into eclipse which should allow me to control external devices connected via GPIB.

This is the contents of the folder that I downloaded.
[image]

I created a new project in Eclipse, right clicked the project and went to build path -> configure build path.

I then clicked on add external libraries and added the JPIB.jar file. The file was added, but I am still not able to use the classes in the API.

Is there something else that I need to do to be able to use the API? Is there a better way of importing this API into my project?

Answer (score 0):

You jar file is installed correctly. JPIB (and many other Java libraries) is just wrapper for low-level routines. So it is mandatory to load corresponding native libraries before using Java classes.

In Eclipse go to the **Run** > **Run Configurations...** > **Arguments** tab, select configuration for, perhaps, `main` method. Then specify in **VM arguments** field:

`-Djava.library.path=C:\path\to\jpib\dll`

Then add at the beginning of `main()` the following line:

`System.loadLibrary("jpib_32");`

Then run already edited configuration. Everything should be OK. But in case of failure you can examine path to DLL:

`System.out.println("Libary path: " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`

Also working directory can be specified in the same tab, avoiding absolute path, but for the first time absolute path is simple and less error-prone.

Also note that Java may not recognize Windows-specific issues (missing drivers, insufficient user privileges, wrong DLL version) and will report about general error.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm still having problems. I added the DLL path to VM arguments. When I try to load the library, I get the error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpib_64 in java.library.path` (I tried both jpib_64 and jpib_32 even though my system is 64 bit). But when I print the path to DLL, it maps right to the DLL as expected so I am confused as to why I can't load the library. Does it matter where the DLL is saved on my computer? Any other ideas as to what I can try next to get this working?

Comment: I've tried on Windows XP 32bit with Java 7. I downloaded JPIB 1.2. Then I put **JPIB.jar** into `C:\JPIB_JAR` and **jpib_32.dll** into `C:\JPIB_DLL`. All other files I removed. Then I created project in Eclipse, added **JPIB.jar** as "external jar". And specified `-Djava.library.path=C:\JPIB_DLL` in Run Configurations. And `new GPIBDevice(0, new WindowsGPIBDriver());` prints 'GPIB Library 32bit'.